# where is the position indicator after executing fseek with a too large value

Tags: c

What happened if I use [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/)

```
fseek(fileptr,10000L,SEEK_CUR);
```

and it returns a nonzero value, as an indicator that it could not successfully execute, because the file was not big enough for the step.

At what position is the position indicator now? At the end of the file, or did it stay on the position it used to be, before execution?

The context:

I want to figure out a way of extracting the size of a file, which has more bytes than long could save safely. Therefore need to go step by step through the file and express the last few bytes with a fraction of a normal step.

> E.g: 2,5 * 100 = size of 250Bytes with a step size of 100Bytes

Comment: Why not use `stat()` to determine the file size?

Comment: because as far as I know I do not have to change anything while porting to windows if I use fseek, but stat() seems to be more OS-related. Furthermore I couldn't really figure out the maximum value of off_t which stores the size in the returned struct, the only hint I got was around 8589934593 which is roughly 8GB, today there are even bigger files.

Comment: Not a bad reason, but a quick glance seems to show that the `_stat()` family of functions on Windows aren't _that_ different. They might be your best bet, along with an `#ifdef` or two. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a failed seek, the file position should remain the same as whatever it was before.

I was going to suggest that you use `lseek` instead of your hack to move ahead in the file by multiple steps because `lseek` works with the `off_t` type which should hopefully be a 64-bit type for you (see also `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS`) but a quick check of some manpages reveals that there is also `fseeko()` which would be handy for you since you're using `FILE *` files, not raw file descriptors. Either way, the best way to seek right to the end of a file is to use one of those functions with `SEEK_END`.

**EDIT**: [aix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/aix) make [makes an important point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839415/where-is-the-position-indicator-after-executing-fseek-with-a-too-large-value/8839526#8839526) which bears repeating: seeking past the end of the file does not make the seek fail.

Comment: as I need the actual size, I would still have to use ftell which, as far as I know, returns a long and therefore fails with big files.

Comment: If there's a `fseeko()` which takes a `off_t` then I betcha there's also a `ftello()` which returns an `off_t`......... Yup, there is! :-)

Answer (score 2):

`fseek()` won't fail because the file is "not big enough for the step". Provided `fileptr` is a valid stream, the position indicator will move to the previous position plus `10000L` bytes, *even if this is past the end of the file*.

It is possible for `fseek()` to fail (for example, if the second argument wasn't one of the `SEEK_xxx` constants). In this case, the position indicator will remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you i will then have to find another solution.